# How to access frame hirerchy in vba IE automation

Tags: html, excel, vba

I need to access the data in a table which exists in the `fraDetail` iframe. Let me know what changes are needed in this VBA code to get the data of the table.

**HTML code of my website:**

```
    <html>
    <head></head>
    <body>
    <FRAMESET>
    <FRAME src="./securityUI/html/login.asp" name="login">
       <html>
       <head></head>
       <body>
         <IFRAME id=bodyIframe src="../../workflowUI/html/inbox_framework.asp?>
              <html>
              <head></head>
              <body>
              <FRAMESET id=fraOuter name=fraOuter>
                 <FRAME id=fraHeader src="inbox_detail.asp?theme=red"name=fraHeader>
                   <html>
                   <head></head>
                   <body>
                   <IFRAME id=fraDetail name=fraDetail>
                        <html>
                <head></head>
                <body>
            <TABLE>
                            <TR ondblclick=launchInViewOnly() class=rowitem> <td>Hello</td></TR>
                        </TABLE>
            </body>
            </html>
                   </IFRAME>
                    </body>
                    </html>
                </FRAME >
              </FRAMESET>
              </body>
              </html>
         </IFRAME>
      </body>
      </html>
   </FRAMESET>
   </body>
   </html>
```

**VBA code:**

```
Sub SearchBot()

    Dim objIE As InternetExplorer
    Dim aEle As HTMLElementCollection  
    Set objIE = New InternetExplorer

    objIE.Visible = True


    objIE.Navigate "http://warp/"


    Do While objIE.Busy = True Or objIE.ReadyState <> 4: DoEvents: Loop


   Dim iFrm As HTMLIFrame
   Dim iFrm2 As HTMLIFrame
   Dim HTMLdoc As HTMLDocument
   Dim HTMLdoc1 As HTMLDocument

   Set iFrm = objIE.Document.frames("login").Document.getElementById("bodyIframe")
    Set HTMLdoc = iFrm.contentWindow.Document

    Set iFrm2 = HTMLdoc.frames("fraHeader").Document.getElementById("fraDetail")
    Set HTMLdoc1 = iFrm2.contentWindow.Document

   For Each aEle In HTMLdoc1.getElementsByClassName("rowitem")
         Debug.Print aEle.innerText
   Next


End Sub
```